# making a new set using for loop, in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, set

```
nums = [13, 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]
index = [1,3]

unwanted = set()
for i in index:
    unwanted.add(nums[i])

print(unwanted)
```

Is there any way that I can to the middle 3 lines of code in one line?
So, something like

```
new = [i for i in nums if i not in unwanted]
```

I'm new to python and trying to learn what, "i for i in nums ...." does.
In a typical for loop, we just write

```
for i in item_list
    ....
```

and we don't add "i" in front of "for". I wanna know what "i" is doing in front of "for".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
unwanted = set(nums[i] for i in index)
```

As for your example:

```
new = [i for i in nums if i not in unwanted]
```

one of the nice things about python is that you can read it as if you're reading a sentence from a book: so `i for i in nums if i not in unwanted` means that you iterate `nums` and for each `i` in nums you'll collect it only if it's not in `unwanted`